# Impossible to display BottomNavigationBar in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, android-bottomappbar

I have an issue about to display Bottom Navigation Bar. I don't understand why I have no issues in the console.

```
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override

  State<StatefulWidget> createState(){
    return _MyAppState();
  }

}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp>  {

  int _selectedPage =0;
  final _pageOptions = [
    HomeScreen(),
    ProfileScreen(),
  ];


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var localizationDelegate = LocalizedApp.of(context).delegate;
    return  LocalizationProvider(
      state: LocalizationProvider.of(context).state,
      child: MaterialApp(
          localizationsDelegates: [
          GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
          GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
          localizationDelegate
        ],
        initialRoute: '',
        onGenerateRoute: MyRoutes().getRoute,
        supportedLocales: localizationDelegate.supportedLocales,
//        locale: localizationDelegate.currentLocale,
        theme: ThemeData( primarySwatch: Colors.red),
        home:  Scaffold(
          body: _pageOptions[_selectedPage],
          bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
              type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
              currentIndex: _selectedPage,
              onTap: (int index){
                setState(() {
                  _selectedPage = index;
                });
              },
              items: [
                BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.home),
                  title: Text('Home'),
                ),
                BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.account_circle),
                  title: Text('Me'),
                ),
              ]
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );

  }
}
```

I use **flutter_translate**. I know it's a very simple case but I'm stuck on it. I search in google but I find nothing which can fit my case.

Thank you.

### Solved

1. Delete App from my device (mobile)
2. Flutter clean in the console
3. Launch Debug in Android Studio

Comment: Here is a link to a tutorial where basic BottomNavigation is implemented [tutorial](https://willowtreeapps.com/ideas/how-to-use-flutter-to-build-an-app-with-bottom-navigation)

Answer (score 1):

Without the location code, works fine, have you made setup of **flutter_translate** correctly? settings delegate and assets like below:

```
  var delegate = await LocalizationDelegate.create(
        fallbackLocale: 'en_US',
        supportedLocales: ['en_US', 'es', 'fa']);

  runApp(LocalizedApp(delegate, MyApp()));
```

https://github.com/bratan/flutter_translate/wiki/1.-Installation,-Configuration-&-Usage

Seens to me that you have missing something in that setup.

Can you describe more what happens exactly? Show some print or gif with behavior?

see ya

Comment: Hi, in my main.dart I put this informaton 
``````
void main() async
{
  Stetho.initialize();
  var delegate = await LocalizationDelegate.create(

      fallbackLocale: 'en',
//      preferences: TranslatePreferences(),
      supportedLocales: ['fr_DZ', 'ar_DZ', 'en']);


  runApp(LocalizedApp(delegate, MyApp()));
}
``````
In fact, I have the HomePage() but the navigationbar isn't displayed. In the beginning, When I added the navigation bar, I have some issue with the route  "generator for route route settings...in the _widgetsapp state."

Comment: I have changed the place for this code 
` initialRoute: '',
        onGenerateRoute: MyRoutes().getRoute,`
And I got the HomePage() without the navigation bar

Comment: Yes you're right without the LocalizationProvider it works fine. I have followed the tuto.

Comment: Fine, maybe is something missing in setup, or just put your scaffold under a Builder widget to isolate and create a new context, can be a option... if helps you, please up vote the awnser ^^ thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can try this,

Bottom navigationbar is the property of scaffold.

```
bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
        shape: CircularNotchedRectangle(),
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 48.0, vertical: 3),
          child: new Row(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: <Widget>[
              IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.home),
                color: Colors.white,
                onPressed: () {},
              ),
              IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.contact_phone),
                color: Colors.white,
                onPressed: () {},
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        color: Colors.blueGrey,
      );
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, 
I will try it in a few hours Thanks

Comment: Okay, if it work then please upvote my answer, Thanks.